# Visualforce - how do i hide/suppress Compact Layout Popup

Tags: visualforce, popup, page-layout

I have a apex:pageBlockTable with columns like:

```
<apex:column value="{!incomePeriod__c}" ... />
```

This value will point to an ID in the database with a text value in the Name attribute. So:

> ID=a0M11000006aUaO Name="Blue Moon"

This will show the "Blue Moon" in my column but have the little pencil and when you hover over the field, the Compact Layout Popup comes up with the "Edit" and "View" buttons on it. I don't want the popup and certainly don't want the View or Edit because its useless and takes the user away from my custom page and back into the SF world.

One obvious thing i tried is to simply make it outputText to make it not editable
but then it will show the ID instead of the "Blue Moon" Name.
e.g. In my display, it will give the "Blue Moon" if i have the above code.
But if i change it to  it will show the a0M11000006aUaO in the column. At least it isn't editable or with popup.

All i really want to do is suppress the Compact Layout Popup so my data will show
up correctly in my list. And have tried all sorts of things for 2 days now. SO, a bit frustrated on not knowing the inside story on all these tricks. Anyone out know this one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

Simply output

```
<apex:column value="{!incomePeriod__c.Name}" ... />
```

If this is a lookup to something use:

```
<apex:column value="{!mysObject__c.incomePeriod__r.Name}" ... />
```

And if you are in a repeat

```
<apex:column value="{!myVar.incomePeriod__r.Name}" ... />
```

or course replace mysObject and myVar with your values

Since I am not sure what your field is, or what the main object is or if you are using a controller, etc, you will have to adjust to meet your needs

Comment: Oh, you are so awesome! One note: I had to make sure i asked for/queried the incomePeriod__r.Name in my SOQL call. E.G. SELECT Id, Name...incomePeriod__r.Name... FROM Income__c WHERE... kind of thing.

Comment: If it solved your issue, please mark it as accepted - if only to keep the question from bubbling to the top.

Comment: Any chance you know how to get rid of the little pencil (and ability to edit the value) of column values? Now that i'm simply putting the Name text to the column/cell, they are giving the user a pencil to edit the value. (doesn't care that it is a value in a db table. It allows the edit)

Comment: Use <apex:column> <apex:outPutText xxxxx /> </apex:column> or just {!xxxxx} instead of the output text